# MySql DB connection getting loss every 5 minutes about one or two connections

Tags: mysql, database-connection

I have checked my database connection, it keeps on decreasing one or two connections in every 5 minutes of the period. I don't see any logs regarding this. Can anyone help on this how to find the exact reason or what may be the reason?

[Please find the DB connection graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRi0F.png)

[SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE "%connec%" result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwHZM.png)

Comment: Please attach database connection code, it will help more to solve your problem.

Comment: So mysql version? Which exact status variable are you graphing? Are these local or network connections? What is the mysql error log? What does `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE "%connec%"` show? Is it an application that persistently opens a long term connection? Are they active? What date where the connections created? What are your wait timeout variables?

Comment: This is the issue with my organisation production server, @JAYPATEL database connection code is added to my RDS endpoint which is MySQL server from AWS service.

Comment: @danblack, I'm using MySQL version 5.7.12, as this issue arises in our organization production server, this is using both network and local connections. but 1480 is the local connections for the application. But these connections should not be decreased at any point, because it is using the application connectivity. In error, I didn't find any logs regarding connectivity. Wait timeout is 28800.
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE "%connec%"  result added in my question, https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwHZM.png